# listing the azure locations that support virtual network

Tags: python, azure, azure-virtual-network

I'd like to create virtual networks in every location in Azure that can support them, using Azure python SDK.
In the code below I'm limiting only to location `germanynorth`, but that is just to help reproduce the issue.

```
from azure.common.client_factory import get_client_from_auth_file
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.subscription import SubscriptionClient
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient

get_client_from_auth_file(ComputeManagementClient)
for location in get_client_from_auth_file(SubscriptionClient).subscriptions.list_locations(get_subscription_id()):
    if location.name == 'germanynorth':
        get_client_from_auth_file(NetworkManagementClient).virtual_networks.create_or_update(
            resource_group_name=RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME,
            virtual_network_name='test-network',
            parameters={'location': location.name, 'address_space': {'address_prefixes': ['10.0.0.0/16']}, }
        )
```

When running this I get the error:

```
msrestazure.azure_exceptions.CloudError: Azure Error: LocationNotAvailableForResourceType
Message: The provided location 'germanynorth' is not available for resource type 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks'. List of available regions for the resource type is 'westus,eastus,northeurope,westeurope,eastasia,southeastasia,northcentralus,southcentralus,centralus,eastus2,japaneast,japanwest,brazilsouth,australiaeast,australiasoutheast,centralindia,southindia,westindia,canadacentral,canadaeast,westcentralus,westus2,ukwest,uksouth,koreacentral,koreasouth,francecentral,australiacentral,southafricanorth,uaenorth,switzerlandnorth,germanywestcentral,norwayeast'.
```

Very helpfully, the error includes a list of all the regions where `virtualNetworks` could be created, but of course this list will change over time.

What API in Azure can I use to figure out what locations (regions?) support virtual networks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure resource providers and types. You can refer the Microsoft [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types#code-try-2) on the resource provider.

PowerShell script to get all supported azure regions to create Azure key Vault.

```
$locations = (((Get-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.KeyVault)| Where-Object RegistrationState -eq "Registered").ResourceTypes | Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq vaults).Locations
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an API with which we can list out all the available location under a given subscription id (I am not sure if there is an equivalent version of this API that can filter by resource type) -

API -
GET [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/locations?api-version=2020-01-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/locations?api-version=2020-01-01)

Quoting the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/listlocation)

> This operation provides all the locations that are available for resource providers; however, **each resource provider may support a subset of this list.**

Perhaps, you can iterate through the list of available locations in your subscription and put it in a try/except block to create Vnet against all available regions in your subscription?

EDIT: Apologies, I realized it late, you are already iterating through the list of locations under your subscription id. I guess it's a matter of writing the code beneath the for loop in a try/except block, wherein you can except that particular error type and continue with your loop?

Comment: Thanks!
I mean, it's possible to try and except all, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.
The fact that they have the list in the error text means they have the needed info in a single place, but I can't access it

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out my own bounty.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/providers/get

***"Gets the specified resource provider."***
I don't think this describes what it actually does, which is why I didn't find it. I had to just basically test a bunch of APIs to see what returned what.
This API will return a list of available locations for the provided resource type (in your subscription).

I just wish it didn't only return a list (East US) but also with the with a short code (code:location), for example (eastus:East US).

So to answer the actual question, if you can't use your python library for this, an option would be to use this REST API:
GET [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Network?api-version=2021-04-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/providers/Microsoft.Network?api-version=2021-04-01)

Your list of locations will be under the json path: **{response}.resourceTypes[0].locations**, where **resourceType eq "virtualNetworks"**

To actually get the locationCode (short location code) you can query this API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list-locations
then map your location from above with this response to get the short code ('East US' -> 'eastus'), which can be used in other rest APIs to create for example a virtual network.